# Rendering partial views with ajax calls in rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.1, erb, renderpartial

I'm starting now with rails, and i have simply question i think.
I need to render two partials in one ajax call:

I have the following controller:

```
# GET /hosts/1
# GET /hosts/1.json
def show
   @host = Host.find(params[:id])

   respond_to do |format|
      format.html #show.html
      format.js
      format.json { render :json => @host }
   end
end
```

And the respective template (show.js.erb):

```
$('#tabs-1').html("<%= escape_javascript(render @host) %>");
```

And a partial file named _host.html.erb

All this works fine. The template "_host.html.erb" is rendered in div tabs-1, but now i need to add some other partial template in a different id (#tabs-2), but use the same @host
How can i do this? by default the render @host method will use the template file "_host.html.erb". How can i call a different one like _host2.html.erb and have the same @host instance available?

Thanks,
Joao

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('#tabs-1').html("<%= j(render @host) %>");
$('#tabs-2').html("<%= j(render :partial => 'host2', :locals => { :host => @host }) %>");
```